# css & html child not affected by container dimensions

Tags: html, css, position, containers

I have this part of code:

```
<ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>second item
        <ul>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is a menu on my webpage. It is printed like this by CMS.
For now, menu looks like this:

```
item1 | item2 | item3 | item4
            childItem3 | childItem3 | childItem3
```

What i wanna do is style child items with CSS to start right in place where main menu starts, so it looks like this:

```
item1 | item2 | item3 | item4
childItem3 | childItem3 | childItem3
```

How can i achieve this?

@edit:

here is the CSS i use. I made this very simple and it works fine (I've had problem with placing submenu under menu, but position:absolute repaired it)

```
#menu ul {
        position: relative;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the current CSS that affects the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I would set the container of your outer ul to relative, then set your nested ul to position:absolute and give it a suitable top value to push it under the outer list.

EDIT: This is how you could change your CSS to achieve what you want:

```
ul { position: relative; }

ul li { float:left; }

ul li ul { position: absolute; display:none; }

ul li:hover ul { left:0px; top:20px; display:inline; }
```

Obviously this has been simplified as you example CSS was. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLwD/

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/EZDhr/](http://jsfiddle.net/EZDhr/) more visual so you can see a difference

Comment: Yeah, thats it! Thank you very much ;)